# radio buttons won't deselect when another button is selected in dreamwever cs5

Tags: dreamweaver

[enter link description here](http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis54/tyson_schweidel/concert.htm)`enter code here`     My problem is that the radio buttons won't deselect once selected. This form is connected to a php file that I build for my homework. In Dreamweaver if I keep the default value for the name   attribute I don't have a problem with the buttons, but since the value of the name attribute has to match the name attribute in the php file I can't keep the default name. I've tried using group buttons and single buttons and copying them. In a text page I was able to get buttons to deselect when another button was selected. And then it stopped working, all the buttons stayed checked. I'm confused because I thought radio buttons contained boolean values, when one is selected the other is deselected. Any suggestions? Here is the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1     /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Homework 7</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function edits()
 {
 if(document.getElementById("name").value=="")
 {
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
 }
if(document.getElementById("jarreau").checked=="")
 {
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
 }
else if(document.getElementById("aretha").checked=="")
 {
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
 }
else if(document.getElementById("withers").checked=="")
 {
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
}
else if(document.getElementById("joel").checked=="")
 {
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
}
else if(document.getElementById("warwidk").checked=="")
{
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
}
if(document.getElementById("rate").value=="")
{
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;

if(document.getElementById("email").value=="")
{
alert("Please enter your whole name.")
return false;
 }
}
else return true;
}

 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
background-color: #F9F; 
 }
 h1 {
font-size: xx-large;
color: #FFF;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1 font color="#fff">Old School Concert</h1>
 <table width="87%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>
 <th align="left" width="19%" scope="col">Al Jarreau</th>
 <th align="left"width="13%" scope="col">Aretha Franklin</th>
  <th align="left"width="16%" scope="col">Bill Withers</th>
 <th align="left"width="19%" scope="col">Billy Joel</th>
 <th align="left"width="19%" scope="col">Dionne Warwick</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="al jarreau.jpg" width="247" height="204" alt="Al Jarreau" /></td>
<td><img src="images/aretha franklin.jpg" width="198" height="204" alt="aretha franklin" /></td>
<td><img src="Bill Withers.jpg" width="192" height="204" alt="Bill Withers" /></td>
<td><img src="billy joel.jpg" width="225" height="204" alt="Billy Joel" /></td>
<td><img src="Dionne Warwick.jpg" width="176" height="204" alt="Dionne Warwick" /></td>
</tr>
```

### In order to keep bringing you the best in old school legends please         fill out this brief survey.

```
 <form name="service" method="post" action="concert.php" />
 <label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="fname" size="20" maxlength="15" />
(optional)
<br />
 <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="lname" size="20" maxlength="15" />
(optional)<br />
 <label>Which performance you liked best:</label><br />

 <p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="jarreau" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0"/>
    Al Jarreau</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="aretha" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
    Aretha Franklin</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="withers" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_2" />
    Bill Withers</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="joel" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_3" />
    Billy Joel</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="warwick" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_4" />
    Dionne Warwick</label>

</p>

 <br />
 <label for="rate">On a scale of 1 to 10 how would you rate this concert?</label>
<br />
<input name="rate" type="text" id="rate" size="5" maxlength="2" />
 <label for="email"><br />
Your email address:</label>
  <br />
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="45" maxlength="45" />
</p>
 <p>
 <label for="comment">Your comments:</label>
<textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="button" value="submit" name="" id="" onclick="edits()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give all the radio buttons the same "name" like:

```
<input name="thesamegroup" type="button" value="submit"  id="" onclick="edits()" />
<input name="thesamegroup" type="text" id="email" size="45" maxlength="45" />
```

Comment: I accept this answer but at first I was confused I thought it was the ids that had to have the same name.